# React router private route not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to set up protected routes using react router v4.

I have the following, which works fine.

```
function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authed === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

However, when I change this code to:

```
type PrivateRouteProps = {
  component: Component,
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ component, authed, ...rest }: PrivateRouteProps) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      authed === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

I get the error: `TypeError: instance.render is not a function`. When I change to (note the `component: Component`), everything works:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, authed, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      authed === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

The render function of `App.js` is as follows:

```
render() {
    return this.state.loading === true ? (
      'loading'
    ) : (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          {this.renderHeader()}
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
            <PrivateRoute
              authed={this.state.authed}
              path="/home"
              component={HomePage}
            />
            <Route component={PageNotFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

Why does the arrow function with `PrivateRouteProps` not work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example you try to render the component you passed in with

```
<Component {...props}/>
```

From the way you defined your flow type I guess that you imported `Component` like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'.
```

That means that **`Component` does not refer to the component passed in the `component` prop but still to the class `Component` imported from `react`** because you did not shadow it anywhere inside your functional component. Even if you imported `Component` in your first example it would still work because you shadowed the name `Component` with the value of the prop `component`. In the second example you did not do that.

This is why you get the error because the react class `Component` neither has a `render()` method nor does it have any other functionality you expected there.

You need to assign the prop `component` to another name that is capitalized, e.g. `Node` and then render that variable. Note that the name needs to be capitalized. Otherwise it will be interpreted as usual html node and not as a react component:

```
type PrivateRouteProps = {
  component: Component,
};

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Node /* assign it to a capitalized name */, authed, ...rest }: PrivateRouteProps) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      authed === true ? (
        {/* Do not use `Component` here as it refers to the class imported from react and not to your component */}
        <Node {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

You could of course also use `Component` as a name which will shadow the name `Component` from the outer scope but this is bad practice as it often leads to confusion.